# Calculated column help - nested if for all not null columns equal low then low

Tags: calculated-column

I have a calculated column (see below) testing the content of six rating columns and it is working, however, I want to add a condition so that only those columns that are not null are tested. A list item may or may not have all six ratings but if all the ratings on a given item are low, then x = Low.  I believe I can use ISBLANK but I can't get the formula to work.  Can anyone help?  Thanks in advance!

=IF(AND([Rate1]="Low",[Rate2]="Low",[Rate3]="Low",[Rate4]="Low",[Rate5]="Low",[Rate6]="Low"),"Low","Med")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

replace `[Rate1]="Low"`

with `OR(ISBLANK([Rate1]),[Rate1]="Low")`

Same for Rate2, Rate3, etc.

Comment: =IF(AND(OR(ISBLANK([Rate1]),[Rate1]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate2]),[Rate2]="Low")="Low",OR(ISBLANK([Rate3]),[Rate3]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate4]),[Rate4]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate5]),[Rate5]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate6]),[Rate6]="Low")="Low"),"Low","Med")

Comment: Thanks so much Christophe.  The above logic was accepted but the test is always failed and the value of my column set to Med every time.  Perhaps I need to test for a positve condition for my first test, COUNTA or similar? Thanks again!

Comment: @Kms if you used the formula pasted above, it is not correct and should actually be `=IF(AND(OR(ISBLANK([Rate1]),[Rate1]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate2]),[Rate2]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate3]),[Rate3]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate4]),[Rate4]="Low"),OR(ISBL‌​ANK([Rate5]),[Rate5]="Low"),OR(ISBLANK([Rate6]),[Rate6]="Low")),"Low","Med"‌​)`

Comment: Thanks again Christophe - I get the following error when I attempt to use that formula.  "The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported."  I am on SharePoint 2010.

Comment: Oops, I had an extra space in there.  It worked.  Thanks again!